# jQuery ajax request for PUT fails, but it is working with Postman

Tags: javascript, cors

I am trying to make an ajax request like below:

```
function updateLastSeen() {
    var url = 'http://my.url.com/conversation/' + $('#conversationId').val() + '/seen/' + $('#senderId').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'PUT',
        url: url,
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(result) {
            alert('Logged out')},
        error: function(result) {
            alert('error')
        }
    });
}
```

The request in the preflight looks like this:

```
Request headers
OPTIONS http://my.url.com/conversation/3/seen/3 HTTP/1.1
Host: m.url.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Origin: null
Access-Control-Request-Method: PUT
Connection: keep-alive
```

And this is the response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 15 Apr 2015 06:16:54 GMT
Server: Apache
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=98
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json
```

So according to me it should work. However I get an error that Method PUT is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods.

I also tried via Postman to see if there is a problem with the backend (which is totally obscure to me) but via Postman it works! So what am I doing wrong?

The request headers with postman:

```
PUT /conversation/4/seen/3 HTTP/1.1
Host: my.url.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Origin: chrome-extension://fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.118 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,nl;q=0.6
Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.1794721550.1428851890
```

Comment: Check if adding a method override header works
    `$.ajax({
        ....
        headers: { "X-HTTP-Method-Override": "PUT" }
    });`

Comment: I just tried it, but it doesn't seem to change the result

Comment: Post the request and response from Postman that successfully works.

Comment: In postman i just PUT the correct URL with nothing else and the response is the expected (the timestamp of last seen of the user) . And this is the response header: Access-Control-Allow-Headers → Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods → *
Access-Control-Allow-Origin → *
Connection → Keep-Alive
Content-Type → application/json
Date → Wed, 15 Apr 2015 06:59:17 GMT
Keep-Alive → timeout=5, max=100
Server → Apache
Transfer-Encoding → chunked

Comment: But what is the content of the request header? That might be able to help identify what you are NOT sending that Postman is and hence receives a successful response.

Comment: PUT /conversation/4/seen/3 HTTP/1.1
Host: my.url.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Origin: chrome-extension://fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.118 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,nl;q=0.6
Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.1794721550.1428851890

Comment: Remove the `contentType: "application/json",` from the request and then try. I suppose it checks for a valid JSON when you insert this into the AJAX request, however, your content for the post is empty, which is an invalid JSON.

Comment: Done, but same issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75257/discussion-between-cyber-rookie-and-kopelitsa).

Comment: can you can this `type: 'PUT'` to `method:'PUT'`?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. The difference that I saw between the two requests is that the one sent by Postman has a request method: 'PUT'. But the jQuery's request method is 'OPTIONS'. I saw on other stackoverflow posts that you have to allow this on the SERVER side. There's nothing to do in the client side. I still don't know how Postman is able to do it and we can't :(